# MongoDB : query result size greater than collection size

Tags: mongodb

I'm analyzing  a MongoDB data source to check its quality.
I'm wondering if every document contains the attribute `time`: so I used this two command

```javascript
> db.droppay.find().count();  
291822   
> db.droppay.find({time: {$exists : true}}).count()   
293525
```

How can I have more elements with a given field than the elements contained in whole collection ? What's going wrong ? I'm unable to find the mistake.
If it's necessary I can post you the expected structure of the document.

Mongo Shell version is 1.8.3. Mongo Db version is 1.8.3.

Thanks in advance

---

This is the expected structure of the document entry:

```javascript
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e6729cc96babe974c710611"), 
  "action" : "send",
  "event" : "sent",
  "job_id" : "50a1b7ac-7482-4ad6-ba7d-853249d6a123",    
  "result_code" : "0",
  "sender" : "",
  "service" : "webcontents",
  "service_name" : "webcontents",
  "tariff" : "0",
  "time" : "2011-09-07 10:22:35",
  "timestamp" : "1315383755",
  "trace_id" : "372",
  "ts" : "2011-09-07 09:28:42"
}
```

Comment: thats totally strange, can you update the document structure....

Comment: I can Insert, Update and Read the collection.
I updated the answer with the expected document structure.

Comment: Could it be that it counts "timestamp" too? Also you could try to find which objects have been counted more than once in "exists" query (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224773/fast-way-to-find-duplicates-on-indexed-column-in-mongodb). Is there something interesting in "explain()" output? Did you rename the field?

Comment: The only interesting thing that explain() has showed is that the number of scanned object during the query is the same. Both query scan a number of object equals to size of the result of the second one (293525): I suppose that the point is in the find() call. I tried to use find({}) but the result (as expected) is the same. I deleted all document with the timestamp field and rerun the queries with the following results:    
db.droppay.find().count() = 101624; db.droppay.find({"ts": {$exists: true}}).count() = 102402; db.droppay.find({"time": {$exists: true}}).count() = 103327.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that is an issue with the index.  I bet that droppay has an index on :time, and some unsafe operation updated the underlying collection without updating the index.

Can you try [repairing the db](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair#DurabilityandRepair-RepairCommand), and see if that makes it better.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably `time` values that are of type array.

You may do `db.droppay.find({time: {$type : 4}})` to find such documents.

Comment: Nice suggestion ! But unfortunately this is not the problem. I tried this query and it returns me an empty results...