# How to remove duplicate entries from an array?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

In the following example, `"Algorithms in C++"` is present twice.

The `$unset` modifier can remove a particular field but how to remove an entry from a field?

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f6cd3c47156522f4f45b26f"), 
  "favorites" : {
    "books" : [
      "Algorithms in C++",    
      "The Art of Computer Programming", 
      "Graph Theory",      
      "Algorithms in C++"
    ]
  }, 
  "name" : "robert"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is use map reduce to detect and count duplicate tags .. then use `$set` to replace the entire books based on `{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f6cd3c47156522f4f45b26f"),`

This has been discussed sevel times here  .. please seee

[Removing duplicate records using MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530580/removing-duplicate-records-using-mapreduce)

[Fast way to find duplicates on indexed column in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224773/fast-way-to-find-duplicates-on-indexed-column-in-mongodb)

<s>http://csanz.posterous.com/look-for-duplicates-using-mongodb-mapreduce</s>

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

[How to remove duplicate record in MongoDB by MapReduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405331/how-to-remove-duplicate-record-in-mongodb-by-mapreduce)

Comment: Don't post just links, one of them is now broken :(

Answer (score 35):

As of MongoDB 2.2 you can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) with an `$unwind`, `$group` and `$project` stage to achieve this:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$unwind: '$favorites.books'},
                    {$group: {_id: '$_id',
                              books: {$addToSet: '$favorites.books'},
                              name: {$first: '$name'}}},
                    {$project: {'favorites.books': '$books', name: '$name'}}
                   ])
```

Note the need for the `$project` to rename the `favorites` field, since `$group` aggregate fields cannot be nested.

Comment: That is the right solution if you need to pipe more operators from the aggregation framework (to to statistics for example). Thank you Kynan !

Comment: in `$group` stage why are you using `name: {$first: '$name'}`?

Comment: @Towhid Because each unwound entry has the same `name`, so you can take any in the `$group` stage, so I'm just taking the first.

Comment: the problem with this is that unwind can generate really big amount of documents in the pipeline (i just ran into a case that unwind generated 1 million documents), and the group stage memory is limited to 100MB by default, and yea, you could increase the available memory, but it is not always possible, neither desirable.

Comment: @SalvadorJuanMartinez in this case you can always go to a full blown map reduce

Comment: or introduce pipeline optimization phases early using $match stage, but this is not always possible, deppends on the given situation

Answer (score 20):

The easiest solution is to use [setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) (Mongo 2.6+):

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {'$addFields': {'favorites.books': {'$setUnion': ['$favorites.books', []]}}}
])
```

Another (more lengthy) version that is based on the idea from @kynan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907596/304209), but preserves all the other fields without explicitly specifying them (Mongo 3.4+):

```
> db.users.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': {
        'path': '$favorites.books',
        // output the document even if its list of books is empty
        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'books': {'$addToSet': '$favorites.books'},
        // arbitrary name that doesn't exist on any document
        '_other_fields': {'$first': '$$ROOT'},
    }},
    {
      // the field, in the resulting document, has the value from the last document merged for the field. (c) docs
      // so the new deduped array value will be used
      '$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': {'$mergeObjects': ['$_other_fields', "$$ROOT"]}}
    },
    // this stage wouldn't be necessary if the field wasn't nested
    {'$addFields': {'favorites.books': '$books'}},
    {'$project': {'_other_fields': 0, 'books': 0}}
])

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f6cd3c47156522f4f45b26f"), "name" : "robert", "favorites" : 
{ "books" : [ "The Art of Computer Programmning", "Graph Theory", "Algorithms in C++" ] } }
```

Comment: I'm a Mongo newbie. I found that I still need to add this aggregate to a updateMany() to actually update the records in the database.  Is that the case?

Comment: @milesmeow it's been 5 years, so I don't remember exactly, but I think that the command above should be enough, as it includes `addFields`. Maybe something changed in the API recently.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator allows applying a custom javascript function to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language.

For instance, in order to remove duplicates from an array:

```
// {
//   "favorites" : { "books" : [
//     "Algorithms in C++",
//     "The Art of Computer Programming",
//     "Graph Theory",
//     "Algorithms in C++"
//   ]},
//   "name" : "robert"
// }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $set:
    { "favorites.books":
      { $function: {
          body: function(books) { return books.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i) },
          args: ["$favorites.books"],
          lang: "js"
      }}
    }
  }
)
// {
//   "favorites" : { "books" : [
//     "Algorithms in C++",
//     "The Art of Computer Programming",
//     "Graph Theory"
//   ]},
//   "name" : "robert"
// }
```

This has the advantages of:

- keeping the original order of the array (if that's not a requirement, then prefer [@Dennis Golomazov's $setUnion answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484730/9297144))
- being more efficient than a combination of expensive `$unwind` and `$group` stages.

`$function` takes 3 parameters:

- `body`, which is the function to apply, whose parameter is the array to modify.
- `args`, which contains the fields from the record that the `body` function takes as parameter. In our case `"$favorites.books"`.
- `lang`, which is the language in which the `body` function is written. Only `js` is currently available.

Comment: It is worth noting for anyone using MongoDB Atlas free tier that this command is not available on that tier.  Still +1'd for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
function unique(arr) {
    var hash = {}, result = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
            hash[arr[i]] = true;
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

db.collection.find({}).forEach(function (doc) {
    db.collection.update({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { "favorites.books": unique(doc.favorites.books) } });
})
```

Comment: By bringing the logic out of MongoDB (and losing their native optimizations) this is almost guaranteed to be slower. While it may be useful to some (so I won't downvote), I'm sure it's unnecessarily inefficient and complex for many.