# Query if duplicates in array without use "aggregate()", only "find()", with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have an intermediate experience of Mongodb, and Javascript is not a language I master a lot. 
I used the solution proposed in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502599/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-mongodb-array) but this is very heavy for my RAM.

I found partially an other way to solve my problem.
Inspired by [this page](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/mongodb-where-operators.php) and [Kamil Naja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54974076/10314460) I wrote this code:

```
db.coll.find(
    { $where: 
        function() { return (new Set(this.field).size !== this.field.length)}
    }
)
```

It's more convenient to write, it's faster but it misses something particular for my problematic. I only want to count the duplicates of integer numbers.

For instance, here two arrays with different contents and both have duplicates but not from the same type:

1. [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,'a','t'], array in `field` from file 1
2. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'a','a'], array in `field` from file 2

With the current code above, it will select the two files, while I want the query to only return the file 1 because there are duplicates of integers.

How can I implement this condition, still using `find()` and not `aggregate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can take into account only numbers with [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter#Implementaci%C3%B3n_en_ES2015) method.

```
db.coll.find({ $where: 
    function() { return (new Set(this.field.filter(x => typeof x === 'number')).size !== this.field.filter(x => typeof x === 'number').length)}
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast. Unfortunately it does not work and I don't know why because your code seems to be totally alright according to my researches. I tried without the strict equality: from `===` to `==`. I tried with `string` as `!== "string"`.  I tried `.filter(Number)`. All my attempts failed with `Fetched 0 record(s)` while I know these files do exist. I will search more.